# Compare two arrays, is there common elements between the two arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to test if one element of an array is in another array.

```
$array_one = array("gogo", "blabla", "toto");

$array_two = array("stackov", "renaul", "toto");
```

I would like to know if one element of `array_one` is in `array_two` ???

How to test that? Am trying `in_array` but it seems to have problems.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[array_intersect()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
$array1 = array("gogo", "blabla", "toto");
$array2 = array("stackov","renaul","toto");

$commonElements = array_intersect($array1,$array2);

var_dump($commonElements);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
array_intersect($array_one, $array_two);
```

Answer (score 2):

Mark's answer should be enough for your problem.
If you ever wish to find the intersect of more than 2 arrays, use this:

```
$arrays = array(
    array(1, 2, 3),
    array(2, 4, 6),
    array(2, 8, 16)
);

$intersection = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $arrays);
```